# Catchable fatal error: Object of class Order could not be converted to string

Tags: php

Actually I got a error in line number-34(pointed in function check_id,if(codition)) and i don't understand why the error is shown and what is the meaning and help SomeOne Explain me and how can i Resolve it(i am new in php):
here is my php file:

```
    <?php
 include_once("Order.php");
 include("connect.php");
  $query="SELECT * FROM `orders`";
$filter_Result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
$newOrders=Array();  

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($filter_Result))
 {
$order;
 $orderId= $row['id']; //fetch row id
 echo "hello".$orderId;

 if(check_id($newOrders,$orderId)){
  echo "kim";
  //$order= Add the order object
  }
  else{
echo " jim<br>";
 $order=new Order($row['id'], $row['tableId'], $row['createdDate']);
 array_push($newOrders,$order);
  }
 $item=new Item($row['ProductId'], $row['ProductName'], $row['Quantity']);
 //include("Order.php");
 $order->AddItem($item,null,null,null);

 }
 function check_id($newOrders,$orderId){
 $length=count($newOrders);
  echo $length;
 for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++){

if($newOrders[$i].$orderId == $orderId)
return true;
}
 return false;
 }

   ?>
```

Comment: I'm taking a wild guess here as I didn't run the code. I assume you're trying to echo out an object. When trying to do that it usually calls the [toString](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) magic method. In case it's not possible to echo said object an E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR will be outputed.

Comment: Which exactly is line 34?

Comment: `if($newOrders[$i].$orderId == $orderId)`...... `.` is the concatenation operator in PHP..... did you mean to use `->` instead? `if($newOrders[$i]->id == $orderId)`

Comment: line 34 is "if($newOrders[$i]->$orderId == $orderId)" @Utkanos

Comment: Thanks for the help @MarkBaker ....
my problem is solved,after using this **->**

Comment: And one more thing @MarkBaker in the _**function if the condition is true how can i return the order Object from the $newOrder whose id is $orderId**_